# Is there a way to wait for value in async python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

Basically I am trying to use asynchronous code in Python. To start off, I thought I would make a Fibonacci calculator. **But** I am having trouble using it, here is my code

```py
import asyncio as a
cache = {}

async def fib(n):

    if n < 10:
        a.sleep(0.001)
    else:
        if n in cache:
            result = cache[n]
        else:
            result = await fib(n - 2) + await fib(n - 1)
    cache[n] = result
    return result

async def main():
    res = await fib(100)
    print(res)

a.run(main())
```

And the error I am getting is

```py
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 4
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    a.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 2, in main
    res = await fib(100)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 9, in fib
    result = await fib(n - 2) + await fib(n - 1)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 9, in fib
    result = await fib(n - 2) + await fib(n - 1)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 9, in fib
    result = await fib(n - 2) + await fib(n - 1)
  [Previous line repeated 43 more times]
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 11, in fib
    return result
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Thanks.

Comment: `await a.sleep(0)`

Comment: `if n < 10` "result" isn't set but used.

Comment: What do you mean? I returned it.

Comment: Your code is effectively synchronous because you only ever schedule one thing (`main`) with the event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed init values. They are preadded to cache below:

```
import asyncio as a
cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}

async def fib(n):
    if n in cache:
        result = cache[n]
    else:
        result = await fib(n - 2) + await fib(n - 1)
    cache[n] = result
    return result

async def main():
    res = await fib(100)
    print(res)

a.run(main())
```